# Asp.Net: menu with transparent background

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to set transparent background of menu for Asp.Net project. I use next code for it:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Solution.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; position:relative">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My title</title>
    <link href="~/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/ByClasses.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/ByElements.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="template">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="logoDiv">
        <asp:Image runat="server"
           AlternateText="MyCompanyLogo"
           ImageAlign="Top"
           Height ="100%"
           ImageUrl="DynamicData/Content/Images/MyCompanyLogo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="menuDiv">
        <asp:Menu runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3" CssClass="menu">
          <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Copy" Value="Copy"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Paste" Value="Paste"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Normal" Value="Normal"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Preview" Value="Preview"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
          </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContentDiv">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="master_contentPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="footerDiv">Copyright MyCompany</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

next "ByClasses.Css:"

```
.logoDiv {
    background:White;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}

.menuDiv {
    background:Yellow;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:88%;
}

.mainContentDiv {
    background:Green;
    float:left;
    width:85%;
    height:88%;
}

.footerDiv {
    background:White;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:2%;
}

.menu{
 background-color:transparent;
 width:100%;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and "ByElements.Css":

```
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

form {
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

But my menu have white background and I cann't understand why. Can anybody tell me, what's wrong and how I can set transparent background for menu?

Comment: If you run your menu will get yellow background not white because it is transparent-ed and  it is in `menuDiv` which have yellow `bg`, clear your browser cache and try again!.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly you need
if you need to remove the menu background color first you need remove .menuDiv background

```
.menuDiv{background:none}
```

Comment: Yes, may be my post is not so clearly as I want. I Will try to describe by screenshoot. Now my menu displayed as http://s24.postimg.org/i2bx25rn9/how_IHave.png , but I want: http://s2.postimg.org/jhdgxtet1/how_IWant.png . For it I set: body.template tr {
background: transparent;
} in my browser, but how to set it in code?